# How to replace quotes and tabs in CSV file for Pandas preprocessing?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataset that is downloaded as a tab separated file, with all columns surrounded with quotes.

Pandas is unable to interpret the file properly.

I need to preprocess the file to remove and replace the tabs and quotes for a different separator that pandas can understand.

The dataset looks as follows:

```
"Period: 1/12/2018 1:00:00 - 8/12/2018 0:59:59"

"Date"  "Power AC (IS01_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS01_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS01_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS02_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS02_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS02_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS03_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS03_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS03_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS04_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS04_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS04_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS05_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS05_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS05_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS06_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS06_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS06_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS07_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS07_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS07_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS08_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS08_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS08_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS09_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS09_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS09_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS10_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS10_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS10_I3) [W]"
"1/12 1:00" "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"
"1/12 2:00" "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"
"1/12 3:00" "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"
"1/12 4:00" "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"
```

I have tried the following with various different search terms in .replace(), with no luck:

```py
df = 'C:\\path\\'
text = open(df+"\\Energy 1.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace('\t',",")
x = open(df+"\\E1 Clean.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

The resultant file is either still containing the quotes or corrupt (in chinese when I open it).

I have also tried using regular expressions of different kinds with no luck:

```py
import re
text = open(df+"\\Energy 1.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text])/
    re.sub('\"\"', ",",text)
x = open(df+"\\E1 Clean.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

I'm sure the solution must be simple but it's eluding me.

If I try something like:

```
pd.read_csv(df+"\\Energy 1.csv",sep='"\t"',skiprows=2)
```

What I get is:

```
0                                                     
1     " D a t u m " \t " E n e r g y   g e n e r a ...
2                                                     
3                " 1 / 1 2   1 : 0 0 " \t " 0 . 0 0 " 
4                                                     
5                " 1 / 1 2   2 : 0 0 " \t " 0 . 0 0 " 
6                                                     
7                " 1 / 1 2   3 : 0 0 " \t " 0 . 0 0 " 
8                                                     
9                " 1 / 1 2   4 : 0 0 " \t " 0 . 0 0 " 
10                                                    
11               " 1 / 1 2   5 : 0 0 " \t " 0 . 0 0 " 
12                                                    
13               " 1 / 1 2   6 : 0 0 " \t " 0 . 0 0 " 
14                                                    
15               " 1 / 1 2   7 : 0 0 " \t " 0 . 0 0 " 
16                                                    
17               " 1 / 1 2   8 : 0 0 " \t " 0 . 0 0 " 
18                                                    
19             " 1 / 1 2   9 : 0 0 " \t " 1 3 . 1 3 "
```

If instead I try:

```
pd.read_csv(df+"\\Energy 1.csv",sep='\t',skiprows=2)
```

I get:

```
Error: line contains NULL byte
```

Expected results:

New dataset with the following formatting:

```
Period: 1/12/2018 1:00:00 - 8/12/2018 0:59:59

Date,Power AC (IS01_I1) [W],Power AC (IS01_I2) [W],Power AC (IS01_I3) [W],Power AC (IS02_I1) [W],Power AC (IS02_I2) [W],Power AC (IS02_I3) [W],Power AC (IS03_I1) [W],Power AC (IS03_I2) [W],Power AC (IS03_I3) [W],Power AC (IS04_I1) [W],Power AC (IS04_I2) [W],Power AC (IS04_I3) [W],Power AC (IS05_I1) [W],Power AC (IS05_I2) [W],Power AC (IS05_I3) [W],Power AC (IS06_I1) [W],Power AC (IS06_I2) [W],Power AC (IS06_I3) [W],Power AC (IS07_I1) [W],Power AC (IS07_I2) [W],Power AC (IS07_I3) [W],Power AC (IS08_I1) [W],Power AC (IS08_I2) [W],Power AC (IS08_I3) [W],Power AC (IS09_I1) [W],Power AC (IS09_I2) [W],Power AC (IS09_I3) [W],Power AC (IS10_I1) [W],Power AC (IS10_I2) [W],Power AC (IS10_I3) [W]
1/12 1:00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
1/12 2:00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
1/12 3:00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
1/12 4:00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
```

Edit:

By using the following code:

```py
text = open(df+"\\Energy 2.csv", "r")
for i in text:
    i = re.sub('\t', ',',i)
    i = re.sub('"', '',i)
    print(i)
text.close()
```

I've been able to read every line, replace the \t with commas, and remove the quotes. However, if I use re.sub("\s+","",i) the spaces are not removed.

I have noticed that the files appear to be preceded by a "ÿþ" character.

Edit:

After poking around a bit, I realized there are some characters that were not visible in the original file. The following code seems to work to remove most of these, but it still does not yield a useable dataframe:

```
a = pd.Series()
text = open(df+"\\Energy 1.csv", "r")
for i in text:
    i = re.sub('\t', ";",i)
    i = re.sub('ÿþ','',i)
    i = re.sub('"', "",i)
    i = re.sub('\x00','',i)
    i = re.sub('\n','',i)
    i = pd.Series(i)
    a = a.append(i)
text.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure you need any preprocessing? Does `df = pd.read_csv('filename', sep='\t', skiprows=2)` do what you want?

Comment: No, that gives me the error: "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 2". 

If I try with the python engine I get the error: "Error: line contains NULL byte"

I have tried with different separators and the most I have managed is to get pandas to read all of the data as a string, or as a dataset full of NaN.

Comment: You mention pandas but are you actually using pandas for anything here? Or are you literally just after a reformatted text file?

Comment: Not at the moment, the goal was to use pandas to read the file and process it further but as Pandas has been unable to propperly interpret the file, I need to clean it before I use it. Note the edit I have just added with the results of my first attempts at reading the file with Pandas.

Comment: You've done `sep='"\t"'` - that's looking for a literal sequence of characters of `"\t"` (4 characters) - you just want `'\t'` so it's the escape sequence for the tab character itself...(1 character - hex code 0x09)

Comment: I had also tried '\t'. pd.read_csv(df+"\\Energy 1.csv",sep='\t',skiprows=2) returns "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 2" If I try with python engine, I get "Error: line contains NULL byte"

Comment: Sounds like your file isn't what you think you've got... not sure how anyone here can answer as to how you should resolve this without knowing the data... it sounds like you've got two issues... the file isn't homogeneous in columns and that the file contains characters unexpected in a file... maybe try passing `error_bad_lines=False` to the reader and see what it takes/rejects and then diagnose further from there?

Comment: @mudo, is possible for you to provide some sample data with your actual file format?

Comment: @GhanshyamSavaliya The sample data is as it looks at the begining of the post ("1/12 1:00" "0.00"  "0.00" ...). That is what I see when I open the csv in notepad. When I open it in Excel, it is interpreted correctly, with columns, rows and values with no error.

Comment: @GhanshyamSavaliya Would you prefer I send you one of the CSV's I have? How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood something, I am able to read your data as is by providing the correct arguments to `pd.read_csv`.  See below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """
"Period: 1/12/2018 1:00:00 - 8/12/2018 0:59:59"

"Date"  "Power AC (IS01_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS01_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS01_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS02_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS02_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS02_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS03_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS03_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS03_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS04_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS04_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS04_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS05_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS05_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS05_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS06_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS06_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS06_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS07_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS07_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS07_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS08_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS08_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS08_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS09_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS09_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS09_I3) [W]"    "Power AC (IS10_I1) [W]"    "Power AC (IS10_I2) [W]"    "Power AC (IS10_I3) [W]"
"1/12 1:00" "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"
"1/12 2:00" "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"
"1/12 3:00" "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"
"1/12 4:00" "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"
"""

with io.StringIO(data) as fp:
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, skiprows=3, quotechar='"', delim_whitespace=True)

print(df)
```

```
        Date  Power AC (IS01_I1) [W]  Power AC (IS01_I2) [W]  \
0  1/12 1:00                     0.0                     0.0   
1  1/12 2:00                     0.0                     0.0   
2  1/12 3:00                     0.0                     0.0   
3  1/12 4:00                     0.0                     0.0  

... etc.

[4 rows x 31 columns]
```

Comment: You are correct. The data as appears here would work. The issue I had was that there were some invisible characters in the dataset, which I had not seen when open the file in different programs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there were some invisible/strange characters ('ÿþ','\x00') in the dataset, as far as I can tell.

The workaround I used, developed through trial and error, is the following.

This works by saving to a tempFile and reimporting the data. I'm sure it's not good practice or 'pythonic', but it works.

```py
    df = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\AutoDownloadData'
    filelist = os.listdir(df)
    ResInv = pd.DataFrame()
    ResNrg = pd.DataFrame()
    ResSens = pd.DataFrame()
    ResCurr = pd.DataFrame()

    for f in filelist:
        print(f)
        """Define una serie donde guardar los datos de entrada"""
        a = pd.Series()
        """Abre el archivo de entrada en modo lectura"""
        text = open(df+"\\{}".format(f), "r")
        """Lee cada linea del archivo de entrada y elimina los caracteres indeseados, reemplaza el tab por ;
        luego, combina todos los datos leidos en la serie a"""
        for i in text:
            i = re.sub('\t', ';',i)
            i = re.sub('ÿþ','',i)
            i = re.sub('"', '',i)
            i = re.sub('\x00','',i)
            i = re.sub('\n','',i)
            i = pd.Series(i)
            a = a.append(i)
        """Exporta la serie a a un archivo temporal"""
        a.to_csv(df+'\\tempCSV.csv')
        """Re importa la serie a a una serie b"""
        b = pd.read_csv(df+'\\tempCSV.csv')
        b.columns = list(range(0,len(b.columns)))
        """Selecciona solo aquellas filas de B con valores"""
        b = b[1].loc[b[1].notna()]
        """Exporta b a un archivo temporal"""
        b.to_csv(df+'\\tempCSV.csv')
        """Reimporta b a un dataframe llamado c, con delimitadores ;"""
        c = pd.read_csv(df+'\\tempCSV.csv', sep=';')
        c.columns = list(range(0,len(c.columns)))
        """Lee cada fila en la columna 0 del dataframe c, luego elimina todo lo que haya antes de la coma"""
        for i in range(0,len(c[0])):
            cln = str(c[0].loc[i])
            cln = re.sub(r'.*,', '', cln)
            c[0].loc[i] = cln
```